# How to display Area wise Data for the following Problem statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following table structure

```
Area    Section    Carrying_Engine

A1        S1           Petrol
A2        S1           Petrol
A3        S1           Diesel
A4        S1           Petrol
A5        S2           Diesel
A6        S2           Petrol
```

Problem statement is we have to display in how much area Under Section S1 and S2 , Engine carried was Petrol and Diesel , Output has to be

```
Section   From_Area   To_Area   Carrying_Engine

S1          A1          A3         Petrol
S1          A3          A4         Diesel
S1          A4          A5         Petrol
S2          A5          A6         Diesel
```

PS : Wherever we have a transition in Either Carrying Engine or Section , the carrying Cost is added into account of the previous Section or Carrying Engine account , for instance ,there is a transition in 3rd row , so here while we move from A2 to A3 , we have used Petrol engine and at A3 point we attach Diesel engine and so in Section S1 , we moved Petrol engine from Area A1 to A3 .
Likewise, in 4-5th row , we move from Section S1 to S2 using Petrol Engine and attached Diesel engine at A5 point but here we add the carrying cost into Section S1 Account only , so from area A4 to A5 , we have used petrol engine in Section S1 .

I am unable to get the logic to solve this ,please guide .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the **analytical function** but I must say that you must have some column to identify the order of the column as oracle does not provide automatic ordering of the records.

I have used `DATETIME` column to identify the order of the column in the following solution:

> ```
> SQL> WITH YOUR_TABLE (Area,    Section,    Carrying_Engine, DATETIME) AS
>   2  (SELECT 'A1',        'S1',           'Petrol', SYSDATE - 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   3  SELECT 'A2',        'S1',           'Petrol', SYSDATE - 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   4  SELECT 'A3',        'S1',           'Diesel', SYSDATE - 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   5  SELECT 'A4',        'S1',           'Petrol', SYSDATE - 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   6  SELECT 'A5',        'S2',           'Diesel', SYSDATE - 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   7  SELECT 'A6',        'S2',           'Petrol', SYSDATE - 1 FROM DUAL)
>   8  SELECT * -- your query starts from here
>   9  FROM
>  10      (
>  11          SELECT
>  12              SECTION,
>  13              AREA   AS FROM_AREA,
>  14              LEAD(AREA) OVER(ORDER BY DATETIME ) AS TO_AREA,
>  15              CARRYING_ENGINE
>  16          FROM
>  17              (
>  18                  SELECT
>  19                      T.*,
>  20                      LAG(CARRYING_ENGINE) OVER(ORDER BY DATETIME) AS LEAD_CARRYING_ENGINE
>  21                  FROM YOUR_TABLE T
>  22              )
>  23          WHERE LEAD_CARRYING_ENGINE <> CARRYING_ENGINE
>  24              OR LEAD_CARRYING_ENGINE IS NULL
>  25      )
>  26  WHERE TO_AREA IS NOT NULL;
>
> SECTION | FROM_AREA | TO_AREA | CARRYING_ENGINE
> ------- | --------- | ------- | ---------------
> S1      | A1        | A3      | Petrol
> S1      | A3        | A4      | Diesel
> S1      | A4        | A5      | Petrol
> S2      | A5        | A6      | Diesel
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: I can see the expected output and output in the solution is same. What is the other requirements here?

Comment: If you see my answer, There is output also. Which shows `A1 .. A3` in the first row

Comment: If we had one more row in the Input A7  S2  Petrol , then how would we calculate the range from A6 to A7 for Petrol engine as the filter condition eliminates the case where LEAD_CARRYING_ENGINE <> CARRYING_ENGINE , But there is a movement from A6 to A7 with carrying engine Petrol , so how to deal with this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever section or engine changes mark row with flag 1, otherwise 0.

```
case when lag(carrying_engine) over (order by area) = carrying_engine 
      and lag(section) over (order by area) = section 
     then 0 else 1 end as flag
```

Then sum these flags in order.

```
sum(flag) over (order by a) grp
```

This will assign each row to group. Now easy, find min area, and min area from next row.

```
min(a) a1, lead(min(a)) over (order by grp) a2
```

You can remove last row which you don't want, using

```
where a2 is not null
```

Together:

```
with 
  groups as (
    select a, s, e, sum(flag) over (order by a) grp
      from (
        select area a, Section s, Carrying_Engine e,
               case when lag(carrying_engine) over (order by area) = carrying_engine 
                     and lag(section) over (order by area) = section 
                    then 0 else 1 end as flag
          from engines))
select * 
  from (
    select s, e, grp, min(a) a1, lead(min(a)) over (order by grp) a2
      from groups group by s, e, grp ) 
  where a2 is not null
  order by grp
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=698b46006018edfdab1dea8817998cc6)</sup>**

I used `area` to determine order of rows, because it's all you provided, but if your table contains other id use it in `order by` clauses.